# How to create new instance of bean for dynamically specified type?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I have 3 classes:

```
class Base {...}
class Derived1 extends Base {...}
class Derived1 extends Base {...}
```

I want to provide method creating new instances of derived class:

```
@Inject @New
Instance<Base> instance;
public <T extends B> T create(Class<T> clazz) {
    return instance.select(clazz).get();
}
```

but it does not work. `instance` is able to create instances of `Base` class as specified at injection point.

Conceptually I would like to inject `Instance<? extends Base>` but it seems to be not supported.

Comment: Please try to use ``@Inject @Any @New``.

Comment: It also does not work. It is not possible to combine those qualifiers together.

Answer (score 0):

Of course I've made a mistake suggesting you that you should use `@Inject @Any @New`... You should use `@Inject @Any`.

I've tested it on Glassfish 4.1.

**HelloService.java**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;

@Dependent
public class HelloService {

    public String getMsg() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

**DefaultHelloService.java**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;

@Dependent
public class DefaultHelloService extends HelloService {

    public String getMsg() {
        return "DefaultHelloService: Hello World!";
    }
}
```

**OtherHelloService.java**

```
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;

@Dependent
public class OtherHelloService extends HelloService {

    @Override
    public String getMsg() {
        return "OtherHelloService: " + super.getMsg();
    }
}
```

**MainServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet(name = "demoServlet", urlPatterns = "/demo-servlet")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject @Any
    Instance<HelloService> instance;

    public <T extends HelloService> T create(Class<T> clazz) {
        return instance.select(clazz).get();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.append(create(DefaultHelloService.class).getMsg());
        writer.append(create(OtherHelloService.class).getMsg());

        writer.flush();
    }
}
```

**Result:**
`DefaultHelloService: Hello World!OtherHelloService: Hello World!`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for waking up the zombies

The way I figured out how to do this is the following:

Imagine you want to process ice creams request:

**IceCreamRequest.java**

```java
public record IceCreamRequest(Flavor desiredFlavor) {

    // This of course could be a class, making it record for simplicity

    public enum Flavor {
        VANILLA,
        CHOCOLATE,
        STRAWBERRY
    }
    
}
```

And you have a class *handing over* your ice cream request (maybe from a queue of request or whichever your data source is):

**RequestProvider.java**

```java
import java.util.Random;
import jakarta.inject.Provider;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
final class RequestProvider implements Provider<IceCreamRequest> {

    private static final Random R = new Random();

    @Override
    public IceCreamRequest get() {
        /*
         * On an actual use case you will probably have a IceCreamRequest
         * data source injected in this class from which you will pull the
         * next request. For now random will do
         */
         var flavor = Flavor.values(R.nextInt(3));
         return new IceCreamRequest(flavor);
    }

}
```

if you have your 3 different implementations of IceCream:

**IceCream.java**

```java
interface IceCream {

    Flavor getFlavor();

}
```

**VanillaIceCream.java**

```java
@ManagedBean
@Named("VANILLA")
class VanillaIceCream implements IceCream {

    Flavor getFlavor() {
        return Flavor.VANILLA;
    }

    // Other implementation details making it different from its siblings

}
```

**ChocolateIceCream.java**

```java
@ManagedBean
@Named("CHOCOLATE")
class ChocolateIceCream implements IceCream {

    Flavor getFlavor() {
        return Flavor.CHOCOLATE;
    }

    // Other implementation details making it different from its siblings

}
```

**StrawberryIceCream.java**

```java
@ManagedBean
@Named("STRAWBERRY")
class StrawberryIceCream implements IceCream {

    Flavor getFlavor() {
        return Flavor.STRAWBERRY;
    }

    // Other implementation details making it different from its siblings

}
```

Now you wanted a mechanism providing different instances of IceCream's (Here is where the magic happens):

**IceCreamProducer.java**

```java
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.inject.Provider;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;
import java.util.Set;

@Singleton
final class IceCreamProducer implements Provider<IceCream> {

    @Inject
    private RequestProvider requestProvider;

    @Inject
    private BeanManager bm;

    @Override
    public IceCream get() {
        var nextRequest = requestProvider.get();
        var possibleBeans = bm.<Set<Bean<IceCream>>>getBeans(nextRequest.flavor().name());
        var iceCreamBean = bm.resolve(possibleBeans);
        var iceCreamClass = iceCreamBean.getBeanClass();
        var flavoredIceCream = (IceCream) CDI.current().select(iceCreamClass).get();
        // Do some other init specific to that flavor if needed
        return flavoredIceCream;
    }
}
```

**P.D:** don't bash me for using ice cream flavors, maybe I could have found something with more differences than flavor just get the gist of it; Also I crafted this on the fly to save yourselves from the details of my use case so I might be missing a few imports and the like. I tried (and got) something like it working atop [Helidon](https://helidon.io/) MP, version 3.2.2